# django adding part of url to static css path

Tags: python, django

I have my css located in

```
static/css/boostrap.css
```

I currently have 2 views. A login view and a dashboard view.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'logins.views.login', name='login'),
    url(r'^dashboard', 'dashboards.views.dashboard', name='dashboard'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When i load up the login page it looks for the static files in

```
/static/css/login.css
```

But when i load the dashboard it looks for it in

```
dashboad/static/css/bootstrap.css
```

login.html css reference

```
<link href="static/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

dashboard.html css reference

```
 <link href="static/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Its adding part of the URL to the path off the static files and can not for the life of me figure out how to stop it.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/Users/chrismeek/Documents/Python/virtual/src/static/templates',
)

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/chrismeek/Documents/Python/virtual/src/static/static-only'
    MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/chrismeek/Documents/Python/virtual/src/static/media'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        '/Users/chrismeek/Documents/Python/virtual/src/static/static',
    )
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you're referencing the css in the login and dashboard templates.

Comment: How do you mean sorry. Very new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using relative URLs to link to the assets: so they always start from the current page's directory.

Make sure you always use a leading slash:

```
<link href="/static/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Even better, use Django's `static` tag to automatically output the value of STATIC_URL, whatever it happens to be:

```
{% load static %}
...
<link href="{% static "css/dashboard.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```